# What are exit codes from the taskkill utility?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, taskkill

In my MSI installer custom-action handler (done with C++) I cannot obtain the SE_DEBUG_NAME privilege to be able to open and terminate a process, thus I have to resort to doing it with the `taskkill` utility as such:

```
taskkill /f /pid 1230
```

What I need to know are the return codes from the `taskkill` to be able to see if the process was terminated or not and the reasons why it may not have been.

I was able to obtain the following experimentally on my Windows 8 machine:

```
0 = success
1 = access denied
128 = no such process
```

Is there an official documentation for these?

Comment: Why can't you open the process with `PROCESS_TERMINATE` access? Is it a system process?

Answer (score 6):

Official error code documentation is at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx

Unfortunately this covers ALL windows error codes, which may well be shared between applications.

However the two you mentioned above are on there. For example, 128 is listed as 'There are no child processes to wait for.'

Comment: This is wrong. [OS error codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-), especially 1 (ERROR_INVALID_FUNCTION) and 128 (ERROR_WAIT_NO_CHILDREN) have nothing to do with return codes of the taskkill process.

Comment: That's **all** the error codes. The OP want's to **only** the error code for `taskkill`